# Add pagination in custom code to show new added products in magento

Tags: magento, pagination

i ma using custom code to show newly added products in magento. Now i want pagination in it. Here is mine code

```
<?php
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                   'image',
                                   'name',
                                   'short_description'
                   ))
                   ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                   )) //showing just products visible in catalog or both search and catalog
                   ->addFinalPrice()
//                        ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc') //in case we would like to sort products by price
                   ->getSelect()
                   //->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
//                        ->limit(30) //we can specify how many products we want to show on this page
//                        ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()')) //in case we would like to sort products randomly
                   ;

Mage::getModel('review/review')->appendSummary($_productCollection);

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

I am using the this on page http://leder.siliconbeachdev.com/index.php/new

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is,set collection size and limit. Create custom pagination on frontend. The modified code will be :

```
<?php 
$pageNumber = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
if(!$pageNumber || !is_numeric($pageNumber)){
    $pageNumber = 1;
}
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                   'image',
                                   'name',
                                   'short_description'
                   ))
                   ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                   )) //showing just products visible in catalog or both search and catalog
                   ->addFinalPrice()
//                        ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc') //in case we would like to sort products by price
                   ->getSelect()
                   //->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
//                        ->limit(30) //we can specify how many products we want to show on this page
//                        ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()')) //in case we would like to sort products randomly
                   ;
               // Here we are showing 20 products from page 1
            $_productCollection->setPageSize(20) ->setCurPage($pageNumber);

Mage::getModel('review/review')->appendSummary($_productCollection);

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

In this way,you can have your pagination on your page. You will be sending ?page=pagenumber by which your controller will fetch the 20 results of paage 2 and show it on frontend.

Comment: Hey @MihirBhende, could you please suggest me on this,like im setting the CurPage in my custom collecion, but still when i go to next page, same set of collection results shows in all pages...https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229743/magento-custom-collection-not-loading-in-pagination-all-pages